# BlueJ Importing custom class library

Tags: java, class, jar, bluej

Ok the deal is, I've made a small class library (*.Jar file) to help make a more visually organized code and to help with some common tasks.

Before you tell me to go to: Tools > Preferences > Libraries.
I have done that, over and over and over again.. I also tried to manually add it to: C:\Program Files\BlueJ\lib\userlib\"jar file here"
And yes, i did restart BlueJ to load the newly added libraries.

No matter what i seem to try it won't let me import it to my project using the import command, but without it, it just won't compile.

I know i can just add the classes manually, but as the class library slowly grow, so does the effort of adding all the classes in that library.

In advance, thanks for your help and consideration.

Comment: If you're confident with Java, it might be worth moving to an IDE that is actually designed to improve productivity, rather than teach you OOP.

Comment: I know its not what you are looking for but i recomend using eclipse, netbeans or intellij. Not regarding this specific question but when it comes to IDE specific questions in general BlueJ probably has not even 1% of "professional" developpers using it compared to eclipse, netbeans or intellij.

Comment: as much as i wanna agree with you two on moving to a proper editor, i cant cause it's apparently the editor we have to use for learning Java at my college. After all this fuzz and we should be confident about knowing how objects work, then we can move on to eclipse.
But till then, I'm stuck with BlueJ

Answer (score 1):

If adding your jar file in the Preferences > Libraries tab doesn't work, you can try adding the jar to the "userlib" directory at `<bluej-dir>/lib/userlib` (where `<bluej-dir>` is the folder where BlueJ was installed).

A third option you can try is adding your jar file directly to a project by creating a `+libs` directory inside your project directory and copying the jar to that directory.  This has the drawback that you have to manually copy the jar to each project `+libs` subfolder that needs your library.  On the plus side, it allows you to distribute your project (library jars included) just by zipping up the root project directory.

Comment: as i stated earlier i already tried to add it to userlib, and the idea what not to be dependent on having to copy paste.  
  
Whenever i add the file to either of the library's i just cant "import utility"

Comment: @SimonJensen Can you post the exact import command you're using and your directory/jar structure?

Comment: I'm using import Utillity.*; (the jar's name) and the jar is just located in my blueJ projects folder

Comment: @SimonJensen You need to use `import package.classname;` or `import package.*;`, where "package" is the full package path specified in the class definition (in the .java files) inside the jar.

Comment: If i place the jar file in "C:\Users\Simon\Documents" and the jar name is Utility.jar. Can you give an example if i wanna import all or the Utility jar and an example of importing a class in that jar by the namer "printer".

Comment: @SimonJensen You don't import the jar file, you import classes inside the jar.  An example import statement would be `import com.example.Printer;` or `import com.example.*;`.

Comment: when you do example.* is kinda the same as importing everything inside the example jar. But still still doesn't get me much closer in how to import it. i tried the 'com.Utility.*' that didn't do anything, it just said package "com.Utility" doesn't exist. i have the jar in my userlib folder too

Comment: Is Utility the name of a class or a part of the package?

Comment: Utility is the name of the jar. In the jar i have a class called Utilities and a class called Printer.

Comment: @SimonJensen Don't import the jar name. Use the class name instead. import com.Printer; or whatever your full package name is instead of com.

Comment: what do you mean by package?

Comment: @SimonJensen Do the classes in your utility jar have a package statement at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I create directory named  "+libs" on my blueJ project directory,
then add .jar to that directory, and restart blueJ ,
that´s help me, and import after that work fine

Comment: This question is from 2013, it's 4 years old. I appreciate the effort but this question lost its relevancy long time ago

Answer (score 0):

Despite the post's oldness for who stumble upon i can say with the newest version of BlueJ (actually 4.1.3) in an old Ubuntu distro(Lucid Lynx aka 10.04LTS) all work as intended per default without any hack